# Gdata python Google apps authentication

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gdata

I have been able to login to Google spreadsheet with gdata python `client.programmaticlogin` function following the sample/spreadsheet in gdata downloaded pack.

Now I am not able to login to my enterprise gapps 'me@mycompany.com' do I have to pass any other arms? I tried with account type Hosted didn't work.

I tried creating `oath2` key from gui, I have my client id and email id generated. Running the oauth sample in gdata asks for consumerkey and secret key. Can somebody advise on this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok I got it solved with the below

```
import gdata.gauth

Client_id='xxx';
Client_secret='yyy'
Scope='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/'
User_agent='myself'

token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=Client_id,client_secret=Client_secret,scope=Scope,user_agent=User_agent)
print token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
code = raw_input('What is the verification code? ').strip()
token.get_access_token(code)
print "Refresh token\n"
print token.refresh_token
print "Access Token\n"
print token.access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-google-spreadsheet/blob/master/google_spreadsheet/api.py) for an example of how to use client login. Its part of a library I created in order to make working with Google Spreadsheet simple.

Comment: import gdata.gauth

Client_id='xxx';
Client_secret='yyy'
Scope='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/'
User_agent='myself'

token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=Client_id,client_secret=Client_secret,scope=Scope,user_agent=User_agent)
print token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
code = raw_input('What is the verification code? ').strip()
token.get_access_token(code)
print "Refresh token\n"
print token.refresh_token
print "Access Token\n"
print token.access_token